# Edit row if it contains a certain character

Tags: database, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that looks like this:

```
'Column name'
 NaN
 [11am-2am]
 NaN
 [9am-10pm]
 NaN
 [10:30am-10:30pm]
```

See picture below for further illustration:[row_explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meMud.png)
I am trying to make all row in the same format such as [10:30am-10:00pm]

```
working_hours_daily=schedule['Daily'] // column name is 'Daily'
c=lambda x: str(x)
b=lambda x: str(x).replace('-',',').replace('am',':00am').replace('pm',':00pm').split(',')

times_daily.apply(c)

open_hours_daily=[]

for i in (range(0,len(times_daily))):
    if ":" not in times_daily:
        working_hours_daily=times_daily.apply(b)

    print (working_hours_daily)
    open_hours_daily.append(working_hours_daily)
```

The idea is to apply b only when ":" is not in the string,

and so I am using not in syntax

But the code is not respecting that condition and applies b to all rows,

So some rows turn out fine: [['11:00am, 2:00am']]

but others which already contain ':' turn out like this: [['10:30:00am, 10:30:00pm']]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Camille

Comment: Can you post a downloadable sample dataset?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are going to do after you treat those dates? Are you using `string` as representation for all the columns including entrances like `['11:00am', '11:00pm']`? After those `strings` are treated the application you will use will use them as `string` as well?

Comment: Well the idea is to first, make all entries in the same format, and later try to figure out how to convert the time they open into a value, ex: 10:00 am - 10:00 pm = 12

Comment: What is the logic for columns like this: `['11:00am', '2:00pm,', '6:00pm', '11:00pm']` that have 4 values? And for entries like this: `['8am-7pm;', 'Sat-Sun', '9am-5pm']`?

Comment: I figured can't get them all ...

Comment: pandas is very powerful, if that data makes sense, it will probably not be that hard to treat it to the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
b = lambda x: str(x) if str(x).contains(':') else str(x).replace('-',',').replace('am',':00am').replace('pm',':00pm').split(',')
times_daily.apply(b)
```

If you could please post a sample dataset, that would be great, so I can debug this code.

Comment: Hey would love to, though I'm very new to the site, could you tell me how ?

Comment: Sure, actually you would need to upload to somewhere else like `github` or `dropbox` and then post the link here. Or you can send it by e-mail 
( joao.avf@gmail.com ) if you prefer to.

Comment: Pardon my Nooby ness, here a GitHub link: https://github.com/WeedyCooki/Cleaning-restaurant-schedule

Comment: @Camille, don't worry :) I am taking a look at it.